# fmincon compile error. Norm not returning scalar?

Tags: matlab, vector

I need to call fmincon at some point of my matlab program. I do in the following manner.

```
nonlin = @supernonlcon;

ener = @smooth;

sol = fmincon(ener,variables0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlin);
```

However I get the error message:

```
Error using fmincon (line 618)
User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.

Error in getTetDataAndSolveStr (line 460)
sol = fmincon(ener,variables0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlin);
```

The objective function:

```
function  [E] = smooth(x)

global LF;


E = norm(x(1:4*LF),2);
```

What can possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: BTW: it is not a "compile error" something like "execution error" is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

There is already a function named smooth. So that is why it appeared as if the norm returned a vector. My personal smooth function was not executed at all.